# Updating GPS coordinates to overlapped locations using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

If I have two many locations overlapped each other, and I want to update their coordinates to make the view clear and be able to spot the locations?

How can I do this easily?

I have more than 512 locations.

I don't want to zoom in to the district to have the view clear, I want to make the points far a little from each other to make the view clear.

Is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the QGIS layer Style dialog, select the "Point Displacement" renderer. This will replace overlapping points with a central point and put the displaced points on a circle.

[image: point displacement]

You may have to fiddle with the parameters to get exactly what you want.